# Set-cookie present in response but not set in browser (Application/cookes) Angular

Tags: angular, setcookie

Hi I'm building a client using typescript 10+
after I log in I receive a set-cookie   with JSESSIONID and since is an HttpOnly true I can`t auto set it in the browser and somehow I expect this to be automated

I need to set it to the browser on every response and gipe it back at every request from the Server

```
  logIn(restUserDTO: RestUserDTO): Observable<any> {
    const haderParameters = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
      'Authorization' :'BASIC '+ btoa(restUserDTO.username+":"+restUserDTO.password)
    }
    const haderOprions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
      headers:new HttpHeaders(haderParameters) 
    };
    return this.http.post(constants.serverUrl+'api/rest/wout/login',null,haderOprions)
  }
```

this is my code for logging in what I`m missing?

thank you for your time

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qES19.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZIoL.png)

Comment: What makes you think the cookie is not sent back automatically by the browser?

Comment: Hi, I'm on the application tab  and under cookies/domain  there is nothing set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want cookies to work both ways you have to include credentials for your requests

```
http.post('url', null, {...haderOprions, withCredentials: true});
```

Comment: Hey, this made my night better I appreciate it, but now  I need that this cookie back to the server, since I receive a 401  
   myProfile(): Observable<any>{
   return this.http.get(constants.serverUrl+'api/rest/wout/myprofile');
  }  

     and the JsessionId is missing from the request

Comment: you have to add {withCredentials: true} for all of the request, that should work with cookies. also you can do it via iterceptor, by modifying all of the requests in your app with this credentials field

Comment: this is the reason why was not working  I got it now, but what exactly does this {withCredentials} ? as far as aI navigate through the internet  set cookies are automatically added to browser storage, and requests headers,but apparently not

Comment: for ajax queries it is not. angular guys took this feature from native fetch API, but this flag is easier to understand. see https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch option: credentials

Comment: very useful, I wish I knew this page earlier